# I want to detect ListItem on which onFling event in List View

Tags: android, listview

I have a requirement to change the view of List Item (in ListView) when fling event of right/left swap is identified.

I am able to identify the fling event but question is  **how i can identify on which item (i want to know position in list)this fling event is happened .**

Comment: In the base adapter class that you use to populate ListView. the getView(...) method gives you everything you need. like index. Implement there

Comment: @ KKD : i am not getting your point can you please elaborate more on the concepts you are talking about ?

Comment: How are you populating the list view ? are you not using an arrayAdapter or a subclass of BaseAdapter ?

Comment: I am using arrayAdapter for populating list Item.

Comment: if you want some action and more flexibility subclass BaseAdapter and use that. you will find a getView(...) method. there you can put any action and you can get index of your array as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best way but you can try something like this:

1. get screen height
2. count currently visible items (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition())
3. calculate height of one item (I assume here that all items have the same height): screenheight/numOfItems
4. if you have Y coordinate of your touch event when fling starts you can calculate which item from the top was clicked: posY/itemHeight
5. now you can get your item: listView.getItemAtPosition(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() + valueCalculatedInPreviousPoint)

I didn't tested it so it may not work, it's just an idea.

EDIT:
And there is also this lib: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview you can use it or look how they implemented it.

Comment: Mical.. i am thinking on the same way but is there no api method which returns me index on which fling event is done.

Comment: To detect Fling you can use `GestureDetector` which has `onFling` method and in this method you have access to `MotionEvent` where fling starts. You can get your clickYposition from there I think.